# Как удалять сообщение о бане пользователя? В телеграме aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как удалить сообщение о бане пользователей

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = await bot.restrict_chat_member(...)
await msg.delete()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]